# Nested ajax call, postbacks on first response

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax, webmethod

I am having a very strange issue with nested AJAX calls. The `success` of the first postbacks the entire page and as a result the second AJAX call `success` dosen't fire. I happen to be very confused with this. Below is what I'm trying to do:
Calling ajaxMethod() on button click:

Page1.aspx asp button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnGet" runat="server" Text="Get" OnClientClick="ajaxMethod();" />
```

JavaScript:

```
function ajaxMethod() {           
    var txtvalue = "123";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Page1.aspx/Method1",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "{data:'" + txtvalue + "'}"
    }).done(function (response) {
        ajaxMethod2(response);
    });
}

function ajaxMethod2(response) {
    if (response.d == "success") {
        var ddlVacancyID = 12;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Page1.aspx/Method2",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "{vacancyId:'" + ddlVacancyID + "'}"        
        }).done(function (response) {
            console.log('res2');
            ajaxMethod3(response);
        });
    } else {
        $("#<%=lblMsg.ClientID%>").text(response.d)
    }
}

function ajaxMethod3(response) {
    console.log('response received');
}
```

Below is my aspx.cs code:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Method1(string data)
{
  return "success";
}

[WebMethod]
public static string Method2(int vacancyId)
{
  return "success";
}
```

A more strange issue is that it works fine when I debug it via F11, while without debugging it jut runs the server side methods without catching the response on the client side.

Please pardon my ignorance towards the language, as I'm a newbie to it.
Also note, that I've tried with `success` as well as `complete`, no luck.

Comment: How are you calling the `ajaxMethod()` function? If you're doing it on submission of the `form` element then it sounds like you need to use `preventDefault()`.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan : I'm calling the ajaxMethod() on button click

Comment: What type of button? Could you add that HTML to the question please

Comment: @Rory McCrossan: have edit my question ..it's an asp button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `return false` in your asp button to disable the ASP.NET PostBack:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnGet" runat="server" Text="Get" 
            OnClientClick="ajaxMethod();return false;" />
```